# Proof that a vector space is direct sum of one-dimensional subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, direct-sum

I was wondering if someone could verify that this proof is correct. I am also open to any critique. Thanks!

Theorem:
Suppose that $V$ is finite dimensional with $\dim{V}=n$. Prove that there exist one-dimensional subspaces $U_1,...,U_n$ such that:
        $$V = U_1\oplus\cdots\oplus U_n.$$
Proof:
    We want to show that there exist one dimensional subspaces $U_j$ such that $V = U_1+\cdots+U_n$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\dim{U_j}=\dim{V}$. Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional over $\mathbb{F}$ and $\dim{V}=n$. Because $V$ is finite dimensional, it has a basis $B = (b_1,...,b_n)$. Let $U_j = \text{span}(b_j)$. Because only one (linearly indepedent) vector spans each $U_j$, we must have $\dim{U_j}=1$ and:
        $$U_1+\cdots+U_n = \{c_1b_1,\ b_1\in B, c_1\in\mathbb{F}\} + \cdots+\{c_nb_n,\ b_n\in B,\ c_n\in\mathbb{F}\}$$
    which is equivalent to $\text{span}(B) = V$. Additionally, because each subspace is one dimensional:
        $$\sum_{j=1}^n\dim{U_j} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}1 = n = \dim{V}.$$
    So we must have
        $$V = U_1\oplus\cdots\oplus U_n.$$

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Comment: The lines "which is equivalent..." and the one above it are a little weak (but the intention, I think, is correct). Try to polish that.

Comment: @DonAntonio By the one above it do you mean the sum or the statement about the dimension of the subspaces?

Comment: TYes, @chs21259 :I'd rather write there $\;Span\{b_1\}+Span\{b_2\}+\ldots $, etc., and would make clearer why is this the same as $\;Span(B)=V\;$ (because any element in the space has a(unique) expression as lin. comb. of element in $\;B\;$ ). It is correct though the writing is a little unorthodox, imo...I though wouldn't take points away from such an answer.

Comment: @DonAntonio Gotcha. I appreciate it!